How to use the EditButton in SwiftUI?
I used the sample code of Apple. However I can toggle the EditMode button all I want, but it won't update the Form accordingly. Is this a bug or am I not using it right?
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    @State private var name = "Maria Ruiz"

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                if editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true {
                    TextField("Name", text: $name)
                        .background(.blue)
                } else {
                    Text(name)
                        .background(.red)
                }
            }
            .animation(nil, value: editMode?.wrappedValue)
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}


This seems to be similar to the behaviour of isSearching - you should read the environment value in a view that is being edited (a view inside the Form).
Example:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                SubView()
            }
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    @State private var name = "Maria Ruiz"

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true {
                TextField("Name", text: $name)
                    .background(.blue)
            } else {
                Text(name)
                    .background(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It's even easier, I will put it in a different answer.

My answer did work in the Canvas, but not in the simulator or real device. So I deleted my answer and will mark yours.
